# opencart detect mobile device and redirect to mobile theme

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, opencart, browser-detection

my opencart theme not responsive anymore, i had created a new theme that mobile friendly located on `catalog/view/theme/mobile/....`
so now my store theme folder have following 2 themes

```
catalog/view/theme/desktop
catalog/view/theme/mobile
```

i know how to detect mobile device then redirect to specific domain address. but that not possible here, if i do this steps must create a new store like `m.mystore.com`

**following code i use in `catalog/view/theme/desktop/template/common.header.tpl` for detect mobile device then redirect to mobile sotre**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
    if (mobile) {
        document.location = "http://m.mytore.com";
    }
// ]]></script>
```

above method not suitable for my needs

so my question is how can i redirect template folder to `catalog/view/theme/mobile` if detect mobile device except create new store.?

thanks for any help

Comment: By *responsive theme* I understand a theme (**just one**), that is behaving differently on large screens (desktops), medium (tablets) smaller screens (tablets and smartphones) and small ones (smartphones). By having two themes, one for desktops and other for other devices we cannot talk about responsive theme. Anyway, what is wrong about detecting a mobile device and redirecting to *m.domain.com* with that mobile theme? If You need a responsive theme, stick with bootstrap for example, but there are tons of responsive themes for OpenCart as well.

Comment: Anyway, here You are detecting the mobile device too late (in the template). You should detect the device in the PHP part (let's say somewhere at the end of `index.php`) and override the template set in the `setting` table - if You find out that a mobile device is detected, just replace the *desktop* template with *mobile* one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the php code for mobile detection in the config.php file.
Then, if mobile detected, you use a different definition for the themes directory.

```
if($ismobile){
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'C:\wamp\www\opencart/catalog/view/themeMobile/');
}else{
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/pharmalife365.com/catalog/view/themeMobile/');
}
```

As long as your theme has the same name on both folders, this should work :D

Comment: I would suggest www.modernizr.com than using this method